# R Random Forest Unsupervised

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm trying to understand Random Forest by implementing it in unsupervised mode to detect outliers.

Here is the dataset I am using:

Dataset: https://gist.github.com/k2xl/5cd9a048ae153275f9c7

If you observe, there is one row with values:

```
XKTVEQAX    570 12980.5 clothing store
```

The amount is way more than the other values, so I was expecting this to be detected in the random forest output.

```
library(randomForest)
library(ggplot2)

data_set <- read.csv("~/PATH/anomaly-sample.csv", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE )
data_set$category = factor(data_set$category)
train_all = data_set
test_all = train_all
#test_all = data_set[0:200,]

rf <- randomForest(train_all[,-1],importance=TRUE,mtry=3,norm.votes=FALSE)
print(rf)
predictions <- rf$votes
qplot(test_all$mins.after.midnight,test_all$amount,size=predictions[,2])
results <- cbind(test_all,predictions)
results <- results[sort.list(results[,5]), ]
```

What I am trying to get to is a graph where the outliers are very big circles to demonstrate the unusualness. Am I doing this right?

Comment: There is already a function in that package called `outlier` for computing outliers, and it uses the proximity matrix, not the predicted values. Is there a reason you aren't just using that...?

Comment: @joran Thanks, I did notice that. I'm trying it out now

Comment: So the outlier is getting better results, but for some reason it's saying some very average looking rows are "outliers". For example, row 82

Comment: So? That will depend on what exactly you did, and how exactly you wish to interpret the resulting measure of outlying-ness. I get _very_ different results depending on whether the prox matrix came from a supervised/unsupervised run, but both cases seem reasonable to me, and in neither case does row 82 look unusual.

Comment: You would not expect at tab-separated file to be read correctly by read.csv.

Comment: @DWin Copy paste it to excel and save it as CSV. I did the opposite when posting to gist so you can see the values more clearly

Comment: I didn't have any trouble recognizing what was wrong. I was just trying to give you helpful advice. Expecting R users to copy to Excel and export is rather lame. Better would to write code to process the text file correctly.